# Corresponding page numbers instead of endnote numbers using endnotes.sty

Tags: page-numbering, endnotes

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage{endnotes}%

\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
\leftskip\z@\RaggedRight\parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}%
  \@hangfrom{\leavevmode{\hbox to 20\p@{\makeenmark\hss}\ignorespaces}}}%
\def\enoteheading{\chapter*{Notes}%
}%
\def\enotesize{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on first page}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on third page}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

And the output for the `endnote` was:

[image]

I need to print the corresponding page numbers instead of the `endnote numbers`, i.e.,

[image]

Instead of endnote number `1`, its corresponding page number should display...

Please advise...

Comment: Try `\let\theendnote=\thepage`.

Comment: Hope this is one of a good suggestion, currently I'm out of station, will confirm it once reach...

Comment: @JohnKormylo Your suggestion works well, can you make this as answer? Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, only one endnote per page?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage{endnotes}%

\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
\leftskip\z@\RaggedRight\parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}%
  \@hangfrom{\leavevmode{\hbox to 20\p@{\makeenmark\hss}\ignorespaces}}}%
\def\enoteheading{\chapter*{Notes}%
}%
\def\enotesize{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}%
\let\theendnote=\thepage
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on first page}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-1]\endnote{End note on third page}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, not only one `endnote` per page, there are some chance to come many `endnotes` on a same page...

Comment: Then they will all have the same number.  Perhaps `\def\theendnote{\thepage.\arabic{endnote}}`?

Comment: No, I need only page number, no need to print `endnote` number, so `\let\theendnote=\thepage` is enough...

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the `book` class plus the `endnotes` package. The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) has its own capabilities for endnotes, which it calls `\pagenotes` to avoid clashes with the `endnotes` package (which I have never used). The `memoir` class provides many means of calling for specifing an
endnote in the text and how it is presented at the end of each chapter or at the end of the document. The following shows something of what can be done.

```
% memendnotesprob.tex  (SE 613810 ???)

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagenote  % to get endnotes
\notepageref   % to get page numbers
\renewcommand*{\idtextinnotes}[1]{}
    % printing of page numbers
\renewcommand*{\printpageinnotes}[1]{(\pagerefname\ \pageref{#1})\space}
%\renewcommand*{\printpageinnotes}[1]{\pageref{#1}.\space} % use this for simple page number

\renewcommand{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}} % set the endnotes title

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1]

Some text\pagenote{First end note} % prints a number (and page)

A little more text\pagenote[\space]{Second end note} % no number (just page)

A little more text\pagenote[\null]{Second+ end note} % no number (just poge)

A little more text\pagenote[]{Second++ end note} % prints a second number (and page)

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Two}

\lipsum[1]

Some more text\pagenote[\mbox{} ]{Third end note} % just page

\lipsum[2]

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

I only indicated the page numbers to distinguish them from other numbers. You can, of course, change how they are typeset.

Comment: Much thanks for your suggestion, but my need is should use `book.cls`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Why? `memoir.cls` does everthing that `book.cls` does, and much more.

Comment: One of my known professor wrote this book and this project almost in Printing stage by using the `book` class file, that's why he afraid to change the class file at the final stage...Sorry...